# Problem using decimal and money in sqlite3 with adapters

Tags: python, sqlite, decimal, currency

Using sqlite3 as the database, I want to keep a couple of decimal.Decimal values, one a percentage the other a dollar amount.  However I saw problems when using sum(amount) on over 20,000 entries.  It was several dollars off.

I thought of using an adapter to save the number of cents and then aggregates should work.

```
sqlite3.register_adapter(decimal.Decimal, lambda x:str(x))
sqlite3.register_adapter(decimal.Decimal, lambda x:int(x*100))
```

However, I would now need two classes as I can not use the same class.  Trying to subclass Decimal became an issue as it uses Decimal within itself.  Fine.  I'll just copy decimal.py and replace every occurance of Decimal|decimal with Money|money.

```
$ copy decimal.py money.py
$ sed -e "s/Decimal/Money/g" -e "s/decimal/money/g" -i money.py
$ money.py
```

All the unit tests work.  I try it now and I am getting a "probably unsupported type" error.  I change around the converters, use basic types.  I just can not get it working right and I don't have a better idea for the problem.

I need some help and have a sample below.  Ideas on how to get it working or a better solution using standard libraries?

```
import decimal
import money
import sqlite3

sqlite3.register_adapter(decimal.Decimal, lambda x:str(x))
sqlite3.register_converter('decimal', decimal.Decimal)
sqlite3.register_adapter(money.Money, lambda x: int(value*100))
sqlite3.register_converter('intcents', lambda x: money.Money(x)/100)

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:",
        detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.executescript("CREATE TABLE example(rate decimal, amount intcents)")

for x in (1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3):
    rate = decimal.Decimal(str(x))/100
    amount = money.Money(str(rate))

    try:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO example VALUES(?,?)", (rate, amount))
    except:
        print (rate, amount)
        raise

cursor.execute("""SELECT sum(rate), sum(amount) FROM example""")
print cursor.fetchone()
cursor.execute("""SELECT sum(rate) as "t [decimal]", sum(amount)as "a [intcents]"FROM example""")
print cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: I must apologize.  I started down the pdb hole and had to slap myself.  A simple syntax error is causing all the problems.  Now I don't need to convert at every point where amounts go in and out of the database.

`sqlite3.register_adapter(money.Money, lambda x: int(value*100))`

must be changed to 

`sqlite3.register_adapter(money.Money, lambda x: int(x*100))`

I now see my expected results of

(Decimal('11000.000000002'), Money('11000'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the register_adapter.  Odd, it didn't cause give me a NameError.  The other solution would require processing at every input and output.  This would negate the reason for register_adapter and register_converter. With the syntax fix in the comment, it works quite well.

Answer (score 2):

There are two simple solutions, and I hope someone has something more direct:
1. convert to a string and store the string in the DB
2. multiply by 100 and store as an integer for money values
Both of these will require a conversion back to decimal.Decimal when the values are read from the DB.